# How to Remove or update a specific rule in AWS Security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Using cloud formation, I would like to update rules in existing security group or delete the old rule and add a new rule. Is it possible?

For eg., if the SG has the below rule

```
  - IpProtocol: tcp
    FromPort: 22
    ToPort: 22
    CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I would like to update the CIDRIP to 10.0.0.0/8 or remove the above rule and insert a new rule with CIDRIP 10.0.0.0/8. Is it possible?

I was able to update the existing security group using AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress and add a new line. However, the old rule with CIDRIP 0.0.0.0/0 still exists and unable to remove it through cloud formation.

Comment: It is not possible as the resource is not created by Cloudformation. Having your infrastructure partly codified usually causes such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon CloudFormation is a service for **creating resources**. It builds a stack of resources based on a template.

CloudFormation is *not* a service intended to **modify** existing resources.

It is possible to **add** things to existing resources where resources refer to each other (eg a rule on a security group), but it is not possible to delete or modify resources created outside of the stack itself.